# #Springb boot code(Rest Api): Require 14 dates in output but getting only single dates based on storeId

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

//Require 14 dates in output but getting only single dates based on storeId

```
public Map<String, Map<Date, String>> findByDateData(String date) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
        Date previousDate = DateUtils.addDays(myDate, -14);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
        java.sql.Date sqlPrevDate = new java.sql.Date(previousDate.getTime());
        List<InventoryTest> data = repository.findByDateData(sqlDate, sqlPrevDate);
        Map<String, Map<Date, String>> mm = listToMap(data);
        return mm;

    }

public Map<String, Map<Date, String>> listToMap(List<InventoryTest> inventorytest) {
        Map<String, Map<Date, String>> testMap = inventorytest.stream().distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(InventoryTest::getStoreId,
                        Collectors.toMap(InventoryTest::getCollectedOn, InventoryTest::getTotalCapacity)));

        return testMap;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details. What is the implementation of `findByDateData` repository method? Is issue with `findByDateData` method or `listToMap` method?

Comment: Yes repository.......@Repository
public interface InventoryRepository extends CrudRepository<InventoryTest, String> {
 

  @Query(value ="SELECT t.storeId, t.collectedOn, t.totalCapacity  FROM InventoryTest t where t.collectedOn <= :userDate1 and t.collectedOn >= :userDate2")
  
  public List<InventoryTest> findByDateData(@Param("userDate1") java.sql.Date userDate1,@Param("userDate2") java.sql.Date userDate2);
  
  
 
}

Comment: How to pull 14 dates in yyyy-mm-dd format?